# delete memcache by key name start with a specific string (gae,python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

i build a blog with gae, and stored many items in memcache, including the paged entries.

the key to store these pages is use query object and pageindex:

```
@property
def _query_id(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '__query_id'):
        hsh = hashlib.md5()
        hsh.update(repr(self.query))
        self.__query_id = hsh.hexdigest()
    return self.__query_id

def _get_cache_key(self, page):
    return '%s%s' % (self._query_id, page)
```

it'll show in admin console like: `NDB9:xxxxxx`,
beside this, I stored any other item start with `sitename-obj`.

In some case, I want to only clear all the paged cache, but I don't know how.
I wonder if there is a way to delete memcache by key name which start with `NDB9`?

yes, I'v found such function,

```
delete_multi(keys, seconds=0, key_prefix='', namespace=None)
```

but it seems that the `key_prefix` is just add to every `key` in the first argument, and I want to only delete memcache by key_prefix.

Comment: not sure if you can delete key by start name, but you can see memcached tags to invalidate some cache

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete keys by prefix; you can only delete *specific* keys, or flush *all* the of the cache.

In this case, you'd have to loop over all page ids to produce all *possible* keys. Pass those to `delete_multi()`.

The `key_prefix` argument is just a convenience method; you can send shorter 'keys' if they all have the same prefix. If all your keys start with `NDB9`, use that as the key prefix, and send a list of keys over without that prefix. The prefix will be added to each key by the memcached server when looking for what keys to delete.

Comment: because the memcache keys in my case are generated by query, so it's impossible to loop over all paged keys,that's why I want to use a prefix. I do use `flush_all` right now, but I really do not want to do so if there is a way.

Answer (score -1):

Use memcache to store all other keys.

```
keys = [key1, key2, key3 ....]
```

When you need to delete keys by pattern, iterate over this value and use delete_multi to delete those keys

Comment: The key of keys might be evicted from the cache before it's children. If this happens, we loose the ability to delete them